# Android ArrayList to ListView for search activity

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, arraylist

I am trying to pass an ArrayList of products into a ListView format. I apologize, as I am still in the beginning stages of Android development. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Search.java:

```
public class Search extends Activity {

// placeholder that you will be updating with the database data
private EditText inputSearch;
private ListView lv;
private String search;
ArrayList<Product> products;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_search);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    search = inputSearch.getText().toString();
    new getDataFromDatabase().execute();
}

private class getDataFromDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)  {
        Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        products = SearchQuery.returnProductView(search, conn);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ProductAdapter adbProduct;
        adbProduct = new ProductAdapter(Search.this, 0, products);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listview.setAdapter(adbProduct);
    }

}

}
```

SearchQuery.java:

```
public class SearchQuery extends Activity {

public SearchQuery() {}

public static ArrayList<Product> returnProductView (String search, Connection conn){

    ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Product product = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE Name Like ? OR Department LIKE ? OR Description Like ?");
        ps.setString(1, "%" + search + "%");
        ps.setString(2, "%" + search + "%");
        ps.setString(3, "%" + search + "%");
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {

            product = new Product();
            product.setSKU(result.getInt("SKU"));
            product.setProduct_name(result.getString("Name"));
            product.setProduct_dept(result.getString("Department"));
            product.setPrice(result.getFloat("Price"));
            product.setProduct_desc(result.getString("Description"));
            product.setProduct_img(result.getString("Image"));
            product.setProduct_qty(result.getInt("Quantity"));

            list.add(product);
        }

        //request.setAttribute("products", product_list);
        conn.close();

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}

}
```

ProductAdapter.java:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Product> products;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Product> products) {
    super(activity, textViewResourceId, products);
    try {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.products = products;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return products.size();
}

public Product getItem(Product position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView product_name;
    public TextView product_desc;
    public TextView product_price;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    try {
        if(convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_product_search, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.product_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            holder.product_desc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
            holder.product_price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        holder.product_name.setText(products.get(position).getProduct_name());
        holder.product_desc.setText(products.get(position).getProduct_desc());
        holder.product_price.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getPrice()));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
    return vi;
}

}
```

activity_product_search:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:hint="Search products.. "/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_view">
</ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

activity_search:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Dislpay Product name, Product description, and Product price -->

<!-- Product name -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Product description -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/product_desc"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Product price -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/product_price"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, error stack:

```
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.softwear, PID: 21043
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2360)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
10-06 01:04:03.431 21043-21043/com.android.softwear E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Shouldn't u be initialing your listView in onCreate() then just getting data from DB then after parsing passing it to listView to get populated? Try to move the initialization of listview in oncreate() then tell what;s problem.

Comment: Remove this statement " lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);"

Comment: Prepare would be declare onCreate of the activity. You only need to update the list view by providing the latest dataset instead of every time initialize list view and setting the adapter

Comment: please give your _ProductAdapter_ code

Comment: Apologies, I have added the ProductAdapter code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have mistake in your adapter in getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
...
return null; 
}
```